# MLE for Average Treatment Effect

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, descriptive-statistics

> Suppose 100 people are assigned to standard treatment and 100 people are assigned to a new treatment. 60 people in the standard treatment group show improvement whereas 80 people in the new treatment group show improvement.   Let $\tau$ = $p_1$ - $p_0$, where $p_1$ is the probability of showing improvement when assigned the new treatment and $p_0$ is the probability of showing improvement when assigned the standard treatment. Find the Maximum Likelihood Estimator of $\tau$.

We find the values of $p_0$ and $p_1$ that achieve maximal value for the likelihood $\hat{p}_0$ and $\hat{p}_1$ and use these to form $\hat{\tau}$.

Each treatment group is indep of binomial trials and we're thus looking for the MLE of a binomial log-likelihood, which is just $\frac{x}{n}$, where x is the number of successes in the trial. This gives us .6 and .8, respectively. I'm confused about how to move forward. Can someone walk me through this? Professor does not give any insight...

Comment: Add the self study tag.